# .Net - Remote BizTalk server monitoring using WMI when the SQL server is located on another VM

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi, biztalk

I have created a windows service to monitor receive location and send port events i.e. start/stop/enabled/disabled/enlisted/unenlisted for a local BizTalk server machine using a WMI ManagementScope class scope:

```
string strScope = @"\\.\root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer";
```

But when I try pointing at a remote machine/server to capture events using:

```
string strScope = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", node.Address);
```

I receive an odd WMI error. The typical remote machine I am trying to point towards is a similar windows server with one small distinction that its BizTalk server is pointing to a SQL server located on yet another server within the network.

After a lot of googling and searching, I came across information pointing at a possible cause of failure being the classic "Double-hop" issue which occurs when we try to access remote BizTalk server when its SQL server is on another machine.

Within visual studio I was not getting enough information on the error that I tried a windows built-in tool "wbemtest.exe" to troubleshoot what was going on only to uncover a long error message such as this:

> BizTalk Server cannot access SQL server.  This could be due to one of the following reasons:
>       \n1. Access permissions have been denied to the current user.  Either log on as a user that has been granted permissions to SQL and try again, or grant the current user permission to access SQL Server.
>       \n2. The SQL Server does not exist or an invalid database name has been specified.  Check the name entered for the SQL Server and database to make sure they are correct as provided during SQL Server installation.
>       \n3. The SQL Server exists, but is not currently running.  Use the Windows Service Control Manager or SQL Enterprise Manager to start SQL Server, and try again.
>       \n4. A SQL database file with the same name as the specified database already exists in the Microsoft SQL Server data folder.
>       \n
>       \nInternal error from OLEDB provider: \"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.\""

I have tried playing with Firewall and DCOM setting under Administrative Services -> Component Services but no setting is working for me to pass on my user's credentials via "impersonation" and retrieve back receive location / send ports information.

Please share a workaround/solution/configuration settings that actually addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and thorough study, the solution was achieved via enabling / configuring Kerberos authentication for the non-domain admin. service account user and machines involved in communication i.e. client (machine sending WMI based request), Biztalk node (machine responding to the WMI based request) and SQL Server node (machine hosting / running SQL Server database engine service and most importantly Biztalk's databases which include messagebox, tracking, management and SSO).

This was all done under a single domain and delegation was setup for both the Biztalk node and SQL Server node along with the service account used.

DCOM permissions were granted to the service account for WMI and DTC(Distributed Transaction Coordinator) permissions were setup.

Appropriate SPNs were generated and appropriate SQL Server permissions were granted to the service account initiating WMI request in delegation mode.

Verified that Kerberos was enabled for the particular service account using the following SQL query:

> select session_id,net_transport,client_net_address,auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections

Answer (score 0):

This is a double hop issue only, the problem you are facing is because you are trying to run a service and access remote server BizTalk server, which is then trying to logon to a remote SQL server. Your credential only reaches to BizTalk server but BizTalk server does not pass your credentials to another server.

Refer to this link for solution
[Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481077/wmi-net-to-microsoftbiztalkserver-login-failed-for-user-anonymous-login)

Comment: I have already gone through provided link but to no avail. All 3 options which are presented in the answer are not applicable in my scenario as all the rights have already been configured for the users in our domain to access Biztalk server, ExplorerOM Api does not allow monitoring events rather allow operations like add/update/delete Biztalk artifacts.

Comment: Have you tried running your windows service from BizTalk server for which you are trying to get information of?

Comment: yes we tried that and it worked but the design is to use a single application server hosting our monitoring service to capture Biztalk events from other machines in the network.

Comment: you can use single application server with in same BizTalk group to host your service, or use powershell which you run remotely on BizTalk server without installing anything on BizTalk server from one application server, Otherwise you are talking about trusting servers and credential delegation setup, which would be done at active directory domain level. This has nothing to do with BizTalk, its how Windows servers in domain communicate using Kerberos authentication.